# LaTeX3: Elegant way to forward-reference a counter with a "future" value

Tags: latex3, parsing

I'd like to do, pseudo-code, the following:

```
\begin{pointtracker}{Advanced Geology}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Count the fingers on your left hand. Are there more than 9? \addpoints{1}
    \item Draw a rectangle with five edges. \addtopoints{3}
  \end{itemize}
\end{pointtracker}
```

To produce

---

### Advanced Geology: 4 points

- Count the fingers on your left hand. Are there more than 9? *(1 point)*
- Draw a rectangle with five edges  *(3 points)*

---

The `xcntperchap` package (which sadly is broken on current Ubuntu) achieves that by writing counters into an external file (using `\iow_write`) and retrieving them from there. It uses LaTeX structure levels as logical layers in which to keep and appropriately reset counts. It requires two LaTeX runs whenever a point changes.

I could definitely adapt that to the use case, but as I then still have to implement a workaround for `xcntperchap` to work on my colleagues' computers running Ubuntu 20.10, I might as well implement something less versatile myself (I thought), in an effort to teach myself a bit of LaTeX3. (Which, so far, is going well.)

So, is it really necessary to write things to an external file to later "forward reference" then in a second run?

Could I, using `expl3` or other modern tools, for example, expand the content of a function, thereby executeíng all `\addpoints` functions ("function" in the LaTeX3 sense), and ending up with the total sum of points before I actually put the expansion in the code. Thereby, avoiding having to run things twice?

Comment: If things are as simple as your example, you might be able to just get the contents of the env, typeset the contents in a savebox or similar, globally get the value of the counter, throw away the savebox and typeset again normally, but now you have stored the global value from the counter. `xparse` or `environ` has features to save the body of an env onto a macro. I hope this made sense.

Comment: Imho writing to a file (I would use zref) and using in the second run is much more elegant and stable than scanning forward.

Comment: @daleif thanks, yeah, that makes sense. I had the same idea, but there's potentially floats (e.g., `todonotes`) in there, so I'm afraid that wouldn't work.

Comment: who says you cannot locally redefine macros in inside that box? before running the code.

Comment: @daleif that's a bottomless pit. I'll be the one to then support "oh, I used XYZ in the environment, but it doesn't work", so sorry, savebox really won't do.

Comment: Then I don't see any way around using the aux.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks! I wasn't aware of zref. But, in "1.2 Basic Idea", the basic idea is that this should be implementable elegantly in expl3, but the author doesn't know LaTeX3 yet, so they did it in LaTeX2e, and I'd really like to get my hands wet on LaTeX3. Sadly, I can't find the cited code that Morten Høgholm wrote that uses expl3 conventions.

Comment: well we have a variant of zref for expl3 in the pipeline. I'm using a temporary version in the pdfmanagement code, but it isn't released yet so its name and the name of the commands can still change, and it is not publicitly documentated.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer exciting! Is there a git repo for that expl3-zref anywhere? Sounds like excellent learning material.

Comment: Not an answer, but: there are exercise packages which already provide this functionality (using an auxiliary file and several runs), e.g. `xsim`

Comment: @cgnieder and Ulrike Fischer: thanks! You both have pointed me towards very interesting directions. I've got some code-reading to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can absorb the contents of the environment and process it twice, once in a box that will be discarded, giving `\addtopoints` a different meaning, namely, to add points.

Next you have the total available and you can print the whole thing.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{pointtracker}{m+b}
 {
  % typeset the body in a box that's then discarded
  \marcus_points_count:n { #2 }
  \subsubsection*{#1: ~ \int_eval:n { \g__marcus_points_int } ~ points }
  #2
 }{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtopoints}{m}
 {
  \__marcus_points_print:n { #1 }
 }

\box_new:N \l__marcus_points_box
\int_new:N \g__marcus_points_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcus_points_print:n { (#1\nobreakspace points) }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__marcus_points_add:n { \int_gadd:Nn \g__marcus_points_int { #1 } }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \marcus_points_count:n
 {
  \int_gzero:N \g__marcus_points_int
  \vbox_set:Nn \l__marcus_points_box
   {
    % the box that will be discarded, here \addtopoints just adds
    \cs_set_eq:NN \addtopoints \__marcus_points_add:n
    #1
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{pointtracker}{Advanced Geology}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Count the fingers on your left hand. Are there more than 9? \addtopoints{1}
    \item Draw a rectangle with five edges. \addtopoints{3}
  \end{itemize}
\end{pointtracker}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can exploit the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{pointtracker}{m}
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g__marcus_points_env_int
  \int_gzero:N \g__marcus_points_int
  \subsubsection*{ #1: ~ \ref{ points@\int_eval:n { \g__marcus_points_env_int } } ~ points }
 }
 {
  \tl_set:cx { @currentlabel } { \int_eval:n { \g__marcus_points_int } }
  \label { points@\int_eval:n { \g__marcus_points_env_int } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtopoints}{m}
 {
  (#1\nobreakspace points)
  \int_gadd:Nn \g__marcus_points_int { #1 }
 }

\int_new:N \g__marcus_points_env_int
\int_new:N \g__marcus_points_int

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{pointtracker}{Advanced Geology}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Count the fingers on your left hand. Are there more than 9? \addtopoints{1}
    \item Draw a rectangle with five edges. \addtopoints{3}
  \end{itemize}
\end{pointtracker}

\end{document}
```

Each `pointtracker` environment steps an internal counter that's used for defining a unique label. The total points are stored in `\@currentlabel` and this will be what `\ref` will use at the next LaTeX run. Of course this might require several runs to stabilize, if you add environments between existing ones.

Comment: how robust would that box be against floats inside?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Not much, I'm afraid. Use the second method, much more robust.

Comment: I'm still happy you wrote that answer, it feels like idiomatic expl3 usage, and I'll be honest, getting good examples of coding style isn't *that* easy in LaTeX-land, plus, our current solution is indeed box-based, but it's a 400 LOC LaTeX2 monster, so if I just write a drop-in replacement first while I convince the team to switch to my new class/package, this is worth dozens of hours of reading cobbled-together old LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

EDITED to be able to calculate global points, as well, by nesting the `pointtracker` environments. This question has inspired future improvements to the `tokcycle` package.  See **SUPPLEMENT**.

The `tokcycle` package provides an elegant way to accomplish this.  It passes through all the tokens of its input and accepts directives on how to treat them.  By default, it echoes them to the `\cytoks` token list, which is then typeset at the end of the environment.

It breaks tokens into 4 categories (Characters, Groups, Macros, and Spaces) and permits a different directive for each category.  Since here, we need to do something when an `\addtopoints` is encountered, we use the `\Macrodirective` to accomplish it.

In the `pointracker` environment, tokens are being echoed to the `\cytoks` token list as they are encountered.  However, if it comes across an `\addtopoints` token, it *additionally* calls on the magic macro `\z` (hat tip to David Carlisle).  From having written the package, I know that the next tokens in the input stream will be `\@tokcycle <continuation of input stream>`, which is telling the package to continue processing the input stream through the token cycle (we know the next thing in the input stream will be the argument to `\addtopoints`, that is, `{<number>}`).

What `\z` does is rearrange the input stream so that `\@tokcycle{2}` becomes `\addtocounter{pointcount}{2}\@tokcycle{2}`, accomplishing our desired goal of counting the points during the token cycle, prior to the tokens being typeset. When it finally gets around to typesetting `\the\cytoks`, they will be the exact tokens of the input stream, but with foreknowledge of `\thepointcount`.

I have now added an option to the environment for specifying the label applied to the number (default `points`).  This will allow, in nested environments, the use of `total points` as the optional argument in the outer environment.  One may also apply a size modifier to the mandatory argument, perhaps making the outer environment larger than the default `\Large`.

I again emphasize that only one LaTeX compilation has occurred here.  However, each `pointtracker` environment cycles through the tokens of its environment looking for point allocations before typesetting, which one may think of as a form of double pass.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle,environ}
\newcounter{pointcount}
\newcommand\addtopoints[1]{(\textit{#1 point}%
  \ifnum#1=1\relax\else\textit{s}\fi)}
\def\z#1#2{\addtocounter{pointcount}{#2}#1{#2}}
\NewEnviron{pointtracker}[2][points]{%
  \par\bigskip\resettokcycle
  \setcounter{pointcount}{0}%
  \Macrodirective{\addcytoks{##1}\tctestifx{\addtopoints##1}{\z}{}}%
  \def\tmp{\tokencyclexpress{\Large\bfseries #2: \thepointcount{} #1}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\BODY\endtokencyclexpress
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pointtracker}[total points]{\LARGE Science Test}
\begin{pointtracker}{Advanced Geology}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Count the fingers on your left hand. Are there more than 9?
          \addtopoints{1}
    \item Draw a rectangle with five edges. \addtopoints{3}
  \end{itemize}
\end{pointtracker}
\bigskip
In this next phase of the test, feel free to use your calculator.
\begin{pointtracker}{Meteorology}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item How many borgs does it take to brew a Danish beer?
          \addtopoints{2}
    \item What is the meaning of life? \addtopoints{4}
  \end{itemize}
\end{pointtracker}
\end{pointtracker}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

The answer above got me thinking on the utility of building some sort of look-ahead feature into the directives employed by `tokcycle`.  For example, in this problem, without look-ahead, I would be forced to define and set a flag when when encountering `\addtopoints` in the Macro-directive and then keep an eye out in the Group-directive for the flag, so as to read the argument which follows, containing the numbers I wish to tally.  And then reset the flag.  The method works, but can be cumbersome.

The `\z` trick I used above was based on my personal knowledge of the guts of `tokcycle`, which clearly, typical users do not have.  Wouldn't it be preferable and useful to be able to define a programming layer to accomplish this sort of task?  Maybe with a syntax like this:

```
\def\z{\tcpop\Q\addtocounter{pointcount}{\Q}\tcpushgroup{\Q}}
```

In essence, pop an argument from the input stream, add the number to my tally, and then push the argument back onto the input stream (with braces).  Here, `\Q` is just a local macro name that the user can choose.

With the introduction of `tokcycle[2021-05-27]` V1.4, the above syntax became a reality.  Best of all, the new `\z` can be invoked anywhere in the directive, not just "at the end", as was required in my hard-wired approach above.

Here is a summary of what is offered new in v1.4:

While the normal processing of tokens in a token cycle gives very detailed
information about the implicit/explicit/active nature of the tokens, the
look-ahead features described below are not nearly as exhaustive in their
discernment.  They are intended to be used when one already has an idea of
what kind of tokens are in the immediate future of the input stream.

In the following descriptions, `\zz` is a representative macro token whose actual name is selected by the user.

1. `\tcpeek\zz` -  `\futurelet`s the next token of the future input stream* into `\zz`, future input stream remains undisturbed.
2. `\tcpop\zz` -   absorbs one argument** from the future input stream placing that argument as the replacement text of `\zz`.
3. `\tcpopliteral\zz` - like `\tcpop`, this absorbs an argument from the input stream.  However, in this case, leading whitespace and any brace grouping is preserved in `\zz`, so that `\zz` contains the literal tokens that came off the input stream.
4. `\tcpopto<tok>\zz` - removes tokens from the future input stream up to and including the occurrence of `<tok>`, in the fashion of
   `\def\zz#1<tok><input stream>`.  All removed tokens***, including the terminating `<tok>`, are `\def`ed into `\zz`.
5. `\tcpush\zz` -  places the replacement text of `\zz` as the next element of the input stream.
6. `\tcpushgroup\zz` - acts like `\tcpush`, except the replacement text of `\zz` is encased in an explicit brace group.
7. `\tcpopwhitespace\zz` - to peek beyond the white space at the running head of the input stream, without absorbing what follows, one may use this macro to absorb the white space (explicit continuous spaces signifying one explicit space token).  At that point, what follows can be probed with a `\tcpeek`.  `\zz` will contain a space if white space was absorbed or empty otherwise. Implicit spaces will not be absorbed by this macro.

In addition, `\tcappto#1from#2` allows the replacement text of `#2` to be appended to the replacement text of `#1`.  This macro has also been combined with both popping forms as `\tcpopappto` and `\tcpopliteralappto` in which the `from#2` is taken as the input stream, and the popped tokens are appended to the replacement text of the provided macro.

The above macros are to be used within the Character, Macro, and Space directives (not the Group directive).  They can assist in previewing an argument when a particular macro is encountered, determining whether a space is the next token in the input stream, performing in the context of one directive an operation that spans over several tokens of input.  I'm sure users will think of many more uses.

In general, use peeked tokens for making decisions, but do not output
peeked tokens to `\cytoks`, as the token used in the directive will
be reassigned each time that directive is called upon.  When `\cytoks` is
eventually typeset, only the final assignment remains.

Example of `\tcpopto`, to absorb, now, a future *optional* argument
into `\B`, including the brackets:  `\tcpeek\Q\ifx[\Q\tcpopto]\B\fi`

Note: if popped look-ahead token(s) need to be saved to the `\cytoks` output
stream, it will require one expansion, since you require the replacement
text of the popped macro. Thus, `\addcytoks[1]{\zz}`.  If the `\tcpop`'ed look-ahead
tokens were part of a group (i.e., if the immediately prior `\tcpeek` reveals an
`\ifx` equivalence with `\bgroup`), then there are two ways to retain the grouping
within `\cytoks`: `\groupedcytoks{\addcytoks[1]{\zz}}` OR
`\addcytoks[1]{\expandafter{\zz}}`.  Another alternative is to `\tcpush`
or `\tcpushgroup` them back into the input stream to be handled afresh
by the appropriate directive.  Better still, use `\tcpopliteral` to extract them from the input stream with their grouping (and leading space) intact.

*When the input stream would otherwise exhibit, as the next token, the
explicit cat-2 brace associated with the end of the current `\tcdepth` grouping,
a `\tcpeek\zz` will instead reveal `\ifx\zz\empty` as true (this is
a `tokcycle` group-protection mechanism).

**when `\tcpop`ing, `\ifspacepopped` will reflect the occurrence of a leading
cat-10 token in the input stream (explicit or implicit); however,
blank (explicit) leading spaces (aka white space) will be lost as the
argument is absorbed, in the normal fashion of TeX.  In contrast, implicit
spaces will be absorbed as arguments, also in the manner of TeX.
The `\tcpop` macro will not penetrate end-of-group } or `tokcycle` "escape
character" `|`, instead returning an empty result.

***As in TeX, `\tcpopto` will break if group absorption is unbalanced.

Comment: wow, "we simply parse the tokens that make up the content of the environment" didn't cross my mind! This is extremely interesting. The nesting is a nice bonus :D (I'm extremely tempted to accept it right away, but in the sense of diligence, I should test!)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you.  I am proud of the solution and your question is making me envision some enhancements to the package to allow some limited look-ahead capability in the token cycle.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Please see my supplement.  Your question has inspired improvements to my `tokcycle` package.